# Do carrots and mandrakes grow back in the same spots?

Tags: dont-starve

I think that carrots re-spawn, but is it in the exact same location where you picked it or just the general locale?

And, do mandrakes re-spawn at all, and if so, do they re-spawn in that same spot?

Comment: Mandrakes don't reappear. They only spawn when the map is generated, once. There are about 2-5 of them on a map. Carrots, however, seemingly spawn randomly at times, but they can be easily grown on farms from seeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Don't Starve Wiki, neither [carrots](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Carrot), nor [mandrakes](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Non-Renewable) re-spawn on their own.

Carrots can be grown from seeds in farms, though.

There is no way to grow mandrakes.

The cheat method to spawn either, enter the console by hitting <kbd>`</kbd> and type:

> **DebugSpawn("carrot")**
>   **DebugSpawn("mandrake")**

To exit the console hit <kbd>Control-L</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no, they don't. They do respawn like you said, but not in the same place.

Comment: Be more specific - what doesn't appear in the same spot? mandrakes or carrots?

Comment: @idan315 Exactly what kind of extra information do you want about "not respawning"?

Comment: the OP asked about both about carrots and mandrakes. Does the answer apply to both? If it does - It's probably wrong. I'm pretty sure his answer only applies to carrots.